FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. flutter_localization
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_localization'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_localization:classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
Required by:
project :flutter_localization
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom'.
> Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/142.250.74.110] failed: Connection refused: no further information
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_localization' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_localization' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 30s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
flutter clean
flutter run
did not help
